# Simple Thread Call

Tags: android, multithreading

I've been reading up on how to use Thread in java, and I'm hoping someone can help me verify I'm using it correctly.  I'm concerned that I should be calling .interrupt() or destroying the thread in some way.

I have a simple script that just hits my server to verify some data.  My code:

```
Thread checkregister = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            checkSystem();
        }
    };
    checkregister.start();
```

Where checkSystem() posts the device id to a php script and waits for the response via HttpClient & HttpResponse.  There isn't any looping so I don't think blocking is called for, but please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: If this is indeed for Android, I would use an `AsyncTask` instead. Read up on [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) - it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to destroy the `Thread`. The `Thread` is effectively taken out of the thread scheduler as soon as `run()` returns.

If for some reason you need a way to prematurely "end" the Thread, this is a bit more complicated and there's been a lot of discussion about the proper way to do it. Simple way though is to just call `stop()` on the `Thread`.